# Get RaphaelJS parent from node

Tags: svg, raphael

Is it possible to get the parent of the RaphaelJS generated code? I use [a converter](http://readysetraphael.com) to convert my SVG to Raphael code, which I don't want to change, as I would have to do that for every iteration of my SVG file. Inside Illustrator, I have a structure like this:

- GroupName

  - <Path>
  - <Path>
  - <Path>

The group has a name, which gets set like this:

```
var GroupName = rsr.set();
var path_a = rsr.path("......").attr({parent: "GroupName"});
var path_b = rsr.path("......").attr({parent: "GroupName"});
```

So they're not nested in the code or on the object, but the path actually has an attribute called "parent". How do I access that variable? I have tried multiple things, such as `element.node.data("parent")`, `element.getAttribute("parent")`, `element.node.getAttribute("parent")`, and so on.

I want to be able to mouseover on multiple paths, which has the same parent, and then run some code.

Comment: The converter seems broken, you'd need to write your own I imagine.

Comment: @RobertLongson Why do you think it's broken?

Comment: As described in my answer which you wanted me to delete.

Comment: @RobertLongson Because it tries to add it as a HTML attribute instead of data-* attribute?

Comment: Basically, that's what I said, yes. Although it's a raphael thing rather than a HTML or data- thing. It's what raphael does with attr and data methods,.

Comment: @RobertLongson Raphael has an "availableAttrs" property. Changing that to "allow" parent actually made it work. 1 line and it worked. I'd rather change the source of Raphael than make some tricky workaround that I have to apply every time. Chance of a new Raphael version coming out anytime soon.. Yeah no.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround hack here:

It's trying to add the `parent` attribute on the element, but it's not allowed by Raphael. Inside the Raphael source code, there's an `availableAttrs` property. By adding `parent: ""` to it, I could actually add the HTML property on the element, then simply grab it with `getAttribute` on my node.

Neat little workaround which I only have to apply everytime Raphael comes out with an update (which is never).